# Vmmem does not automatically shut down after closing WSL2/WSLG/Vs Code on windows 11

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ram, wsl-2

I've been using WSL on VSCode.  I've noticed recently that after closing either VSCode, or a single WSL terminal, a process called `vmmem` keeps using lots of RAM.

I've found how to shut it down  manually in CMD or PowerShell using the following command:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

But I've been trying to find a way to make it close itself when I either close the WSL terminal or VSCode.

This problem hasn't occurred in the past, meaning it's most likely cause by a Windows update.

I've tried updating my WSL and updating my Windows version, but all my research has led to nothing so far.

Here is the current version I'm on for WSL:

```
Version WSL : 0.70.4.0
Version du noyau : 5.15.68.1
Version WSLg : 1.0.45
Version MSRDC : 1.2.3575
Version direct3D : 1.606.4
Version de DXCore : 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
version Windows : 10.0.22000.1098
```

Comment: I thought this process was related to Docker - is that running by chance?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You mentioned that you upgraded your WSL release.  What release are you using now?  `wsl --version` (if on a recent release) will give some useful information.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74426026/edit) your question to include it.  It honestly shouldn't matter, but I'd be happy to try to test with that exact release. 
 Also, if using a recent release, are you using Systemd in WSL?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, docker is not running,
I will add the version in the post, but here is the result of the command
Version WSL : 0.70.4.0
Version du noyau : 5.15.68.1
Version WSLg : 1.0.45
Version MSRDC : 1.2.3575
Version direct3D : 1.606.4
Version de DXCore : 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
version Windows : 10.0.22000.1098
I am currently running Ubuntu 20.0.4 on the wsl if that's the question about systemd

Comment: Ah, and forgot to respond to @TimothyG. -- `vmmem` is actually the WSL2 virtual memory manager, which always runs when WSL2 is running.  Running Docker will, of course, cause it to run, but only because Docker Desktop uses WSL2. ;-)

Comment: I'd like to also mention i've  downloaded the "windows subsystem linux preview" on the microsoft store a few months ago to update my wslg, (to fix a previous problem i had)

Comment: @Telli Good info.  But, since you are showing `0.70.4`, it seems that WSL automatically upgraded again at some point, since that's the latest-and-greatest Store release ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Vmmem` is a process that runs as part of the WSL2 Virtual Machine.  And yes, a `wsl --shutdown` will terminate the VM itself (along with any distributions running inside it).

Typically, WSL2 terminates in two stages:

- First, when there are no "interactively started processes" (foreground or background) in a WSL2 distribution, it will terminate after 15 seconds.  This is currently non-configurable.
- Second, when *all* running WSL2 distributions have terminated, the WSL2 VM itself will shutdown after 60 seconds.  This value is configurable on recent WSL2 releases on Windows 11.  At this point, `Vmmem` should end and release its memory.

The first thing to check when `Vmmem` won't terminate is whether a distribution is still running.  From PowerShell or CMD:

```
wsl -l -v
# wsl --list --verbose
```

If any WSL2 distributions are still in the `Running` state (and my guess is that one is, for you), then the WSL2 VM (and thus the Vmmem process) will also still be running.

Assuming that you are running just one distribution:

```
wsl -e ps axjff
```

If you aren't running Systemd, the only things that should be running are:

- `init` processes
- The `ps` command itself
- `plan9`, a fairly new process in WSL2 (starting in 0.70.0), but that won't prevent the distribution from terminating.

If you *are* running Systemd, then there will be a lot of additional services.  However, anything started by Systemd itself (the `/sbin/init`) should not prevent a WSL2 distribution from terminating.

I noticed a spurious `xsel` in one of my (non-Systemd) releases when checking just now, but I think that was simply due to installing the Fish shell.  It was, however, preventing Ubuntu from terminating, and thus preventing the WSL2 VM from shutting down.

Is anything from the VSCode "WSL server" left over for you?  Or something from your development that is spawning a background process?

Comment: Maybe i haven't been patient enough and never waited more than 60 seconds. I gave the vmmem a fair 3 mins just now to shutdown (it did not). After confirming wsl was running with wsl -l -v, i checked the running processes, which are /init, plan9 --control-socket 5 --log-level 4 --server-fd 6 --log-t , sshd listener 0 of 10-100 startups, and the ps you mentionned accordingly. I've recently been developping a web server with sockets in c++ (that i terminated before closing vs code) and also at the start, sshd is because i previously did a graphical project on windows 10 and it was necessary

Comment: I've also, just removed the sshd startup on launch of wsl, but i have no idea why the: plan9 --control-socket 5 --log-level 4 --server-fd-6 --log-t is still running ? Is my web server leaking fd? Maybe it did not terminate correctly when i sent a SIGINT signal ?
I will now try running wsl --shutdown, starting vs code again and avoid launching the webserver, i'll just run a simple hello world program and close vs code to see what happens

Comment: Update: vmmem did in fact shutdown after 60 seconds when i ran other programs, the problem does seem to come from my webserver program..
Thank you for your time

Comment: @Telli Good to hear!  Please do remember to accept the answer when you get a chance, otherwise Community Bot will 'bump' it every now and then.  Also, the `plan9` is just a new part of WSL - Nothing to worry about there.

Comment: Oh, if the plan9 is a normal thing there is a problem with the wsl then ? Since nothing else is running and stopping vmmem from terminating (plan9 --control socket 5 --log level 4 --server-fd 6 --log-t is all on the same line when i check for running programs).

Comment: @Telli I thought you said that terminating your webserver process was what allowed it to shutdown?  `plan9` shouldn't prevent it from shutting down.  Your web server application (which is likely a daemon) and/or `sshd` would definitely prevent it from self-terminating.